# Adding column at specific location vs at the end of data table

Tags: sql-server, performance

In SQL Server is adding a new column at the end of the table faster than adding it at a specific location?

I have to add 20 new columns to a table that already has 250 columns and roughly 2M records. The new columns are null, float columns. Adding single column took me more than 10 minutes. I'm looking for any way to speed up the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SSMS, you should know that under the hood it is creating a new table with new columns then inserting the data from the original table, redoing all the keys and constraints, dropping the old table and then renaming the new table to use the old table's name.

It is probably better practice to add the row at the end and you can use then T-SQL in an order you want for retrieval.

Another note, if you're not locking the db or don't put it in single user mode it will take longer to run.

tl;dr - do not add column at specific position unless you have time to waste

Answer (score 2):

Are you using?:
`ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype`

Or are you using the SSMS designer? SSMS designer may drop and recreate the table (a temporary table is created to hold the data temporarily) - this may be why it is taking a longer time.

Comment: The one I tried I added using SSMS designer. Still, is there any performance gain (or loss) when appending at the end rather than in the middle of a table?

Comment: For table operation DDL ALTER in SQL Server, currently a column cannot be added to a specific location without dropping and recreating the table - which would take some time considering the number of records in the table that needs to be moved to the new table.
For query performance, apart from column store indexes introduced in SQL server 2012, SQL server reads a whole row containing all columns together - so where the column is in a table does not matter.